# Android alarm for calendar events?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Is there any kind of app that creates alarm-clock style alarms for calendar events?

I use the alarm feature in the built-in clock Android app all the time to notify myself of repeating events.

I also use Google Calendar to remind myself of repeating events.

However, for some bizarre reason, Google has refused to implement any link between the two, nor create any usable kind of alarm feature for their calendar. They have an email and popup notification, but these are worthless. Unless you check your email every 5 minutes, or have the calendar web app open in a desktop browser 24/7, you won't see either notification.

This means I miss a lot of calendar events.

I can't be the only person who has this problem.

How do you link the calendar to the alarm clock so if you have an import event scheduled a couple weeks out, you can say, "blare an audible alarm on my phone 10 minutes before this so I don't forget about it"?

Answer (score 0):

I use **Business Calendar** app.  I use the paid-up version but you can use the free version.

- It will link to many Google accounts and bring all the calendar entries into one view, where you can choose to view them together or separately.
- It's a two-way link, so any appointments made on it will go to Google.
- It will also dynamically notify you at the appropriate time (appointment time - reminder time).
- It has numerous settings for the display.
- It has a widget as well (I use it for a permanent display on my second home page).

[App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal&gl=US&pli=1)

This is the multi-account view.

[image: Multi Account View]

I am not associated with it in any way.